# Creating an S3 bucket policy that allows access to Cloudfront but restricts access to anyone else

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following policy:

```
{
        "Version": "2008-10-17",
        "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "Stmt1395852960432",
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": [
                        "*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E1IYJC432545JN"
                },
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

However, this is denying requests from all requestors, even Cloudfront. What is the correct way to do this?

The problem is that objects are created by the client with public read. I currently do not have immediate control of the client to change this setting. So what I want is to have a policy that overrides individual object ACL. So *default deny* here does not work.

Answer (score 39):

The S3 policy will look like something like this:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YYYYYYYYYYYYY.com/*"
    }
 ]
}
```

But, I  didnt manually generate this. When you add an origin (S3) in cloudfront, you have an option to "Restrict Bucket Access" - tell "Yes" here and move forward. Cloudfront configuration will do the rest automatically for you.

Details here: [Using an Origin Access Identity to Restrict Access to Your Amazon S3 Content - Amazon CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).

Comment: I had the same issue.  The AWS man pages are terrible to read.  For me I missed the `Origins` tab and the `Yes, Update Bucket Policy` after adding an Identity.

Answer (score 15):

This is what you're looking for. Replace XXXXXXXXXXXXXX with you origin access id

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotPrincipal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your.bucket.com/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your.bucket.com/*"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: If you still get an XML based AccessDenied error, make sure to specify your default root object in the CloudFront Distribution, under the General Tab.

Comment: After adding the policy to S3 Bucket, I'm still getting access denied when visiting my S3 Bucket via CloudFront Domain.

Comment: Where do I find the OAI of my cloudfront distribution?

Answer (score 6):

For people having trouble finding their OAI, this might be an easy workaround (Source:  [Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#oac-permission-to-access-s3))

- Configure your Bucket like:

  - *Block public access*: Off
  - Bucket Policy: ↓

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::<YOUR_AMAZON_ACCOUNT_ID>:distribution/<CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

- The Amazon account ID should be no problem to find, as it's part of your credentials
- Cloutfront distribution ID can be found in the listing of all your cloud front distributions:
  [image]